# React Router - Nested Routes for Sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

I have a question regarding routing in a react client CMS app that I'm working on. We use `react-router` but this question has to do with routing in general.

While the user visits a page of a website, we have a drawer/sidebar which allows the user to manage basic entities of the website like pages, media, users etc. Currently we are using redux actions to show/hide elements in the page. We found this a little bit confusing and not very practical. We want to change that and to move this navigation functionality to the router. We use react-router of course.

We are thinking to add some additional routes to the app in order to keep the currently visible page in the url. For example consider that the user opens the app and visits a page:

`#app/page/someflag`

Now consider that the user wants to manage users:

`#app/page/someflag/manage/users`

In this case a sidebar/drawer appears with a list of the users and when we click to edit one of them we can have a route like:

`#app/page/someflag/manage/users/edit/10`

Do you thing these routes are ok? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some schematic pictures or explain a bit more? I guess you can do this with composition but not exactly clear of the question.

Comment: Hi Prasanna, thanks for your feedback. My question is if this idea sounds complicated or a bad practice. I was thinking to use nested Routes and yes to use composition to display or hide stuff in the forms. The only difficult that I see has to do with the navigation. For example when you are in the first route, the Link component must contain the currently edited page. Not sure if I answer to your question. Do you guys have alternative thoughts about the implementation?

Comment: sounds complicated and like a bad pattern, either manage it within the sidebar component state or push user management to be its own page

Comment: @jakee Currently we are doing something like that. We use redux to manage the state of the sidebar forms. But imagine that like the users example above we have multiple entities like pages, media etc. And some of them have nested forms. So there are multiple isThisVisible booleans in our state...